# Can't read Cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

I created cookies inside the root of my server.

```
setcookie("hs_aff", $_GET["aff_id"], time()+(3600 * 24 * 7), '/');
setcookie("hs_aff_ref", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time()+(3600 * 24 * 7), '/');
```

It exists, and can be read in the root.

But then I moved to:

`http://hafoslevy.cz/objednat-slevu/5219/celkove-kosmeticke-osetreni-pleti-ktere-obsahuje-odliceni-cisteni-ultrazvukove-spachtle-peeling-laser-masaz-maska-arganove-serum-kolagen-a-liftingovy-krem-to-vse-za-neskutecnych-332-kc`

And when I called var_dump() here, I didn't get these two.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks.

Comment: not enough information. eventually you are on root with a www. in front. then the cookie is not readable.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, could you help me to make it readable everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifiy the domain. If it should work for ALL subdomains you should be good with':

```
setcookie("hs_aff", $_GET["aff_id"], time()+(3600 * 24 * 7), '/', '.yourdomain.tld');
setcookie("hs_aff_ref", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time()+(3600 * 24 * 7), '/', '.yourdomain.tld');
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Will accept this soon as possible.